# A question about definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, analysis, definite-integrals

When I was doing revision for definite integral, I got confused with one step.

Here is the statement:

For all continuous functions $f$ which are continuous at $0$:

$$\lim_{ε\to 0}\int_{-ε}^ε f(x)·D(x,ε)dx = f(0)·\lim_{ε\to 0}\int_{-ε}^ε D(x,ε)dx$$

where $D(x,ε)$is the Dirac Delta function.

But I don't really understand why is this true. Could anyone tell me the steps between them?

---

**Rewritten as a teaching exercise:**

Please explain why for all functions $f$ continuous at $0$:

$$\lim\limits_{\epsilon \to 0} \int\limits_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon f(x) \delta(x)\ dx = f(0) \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int\limits_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon \delta(x)\ dx = f(0).$$

where $\delta$ is a Dirac delta function.

---

Here is the definition of Dirac delta function

$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\delta(t;\epsilon)=0\quad\forall t\neq0$$
and
$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(t;\epsilon)dt=1$$

Comment: Take $f=1$ a constant function. Then the integral equals $2\epsilon$ which tends to $0$ when $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: @ANOOB:  You're new here (as revealed by your reputation), so I urge you to learn from experts here on how to ask question.  "When I was doing revision for definite integral" is both ungrammatical ("doing revision"??), but also unnecessary and hence a waste of your readers' time.  Also, the fact that you're "confused" is implicit in the fact that you're asking a question.  You don't need to restate it.  You also have many errors in *MathJax*, which is an added burden on readers.  "Here is the statement" is redundant:  just give the statement.  I'll post a better question below, so you see.

Comment: What is your definition of $D(x,\varepsilon)$ ?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Thank you so much for the correction! This is my first time asking a question so sorry about the errors I have made!

Comment: @Tuvasbien I have added the definition, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function $f(x)=6$. Then, as you can see easily the integral $\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon}f(x)=0$ , as $\epsilon$ goes to 0,  not $f(0)$.